# Why is hotjar never taking the initial screenshot?

Tags: hotjar

I am trying to setup hotjar heatmaps on a react application.

Setting it with all default options [worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbtEt.png) (by default options, i mean not touching the "advanced options" tab)

But the first thing in the page is a loading bar, before the content appears, so the heatmap is [not really useful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIzkN.png)

Luckily, hotjar has a treatment for this that is well documented on [this page](https://help.hotjar.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004925634)

I followed all steps and the view count is increasing, but the screenshot is [never taken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR2G0.jpg)

Any help? There will be a loading of a few seconds on every page so, unless I can configure the delayed screenshot, hotjar won't be of much use, unfortunately, but if it does work, it's gonna kick ass on our UX research

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have said, using the default settings, the screenshot will be taken immediately when the target page is loaded for first time.

**In order to get a delayed screenshot you need to:**

**1)** Start creating a heat-map

**2)** On the 3rd step, enter the page/s URL that you want to track.

**3)** Click on `Advanced options`

**4)** Enter the full URL to the page from which you want the screenshot to be taken and also add the `hjDelay` parameter to delay the screenshot. The delay is in milliseconds.

**e.g.** If the page you wish to record has an URL `https://example.com` you need to enter `https://example.com/?hjDelay=10000` to take a screenshot from the page 10 seconds after it is loaded. Alternatively, if the page already has query strings, `https://example.com/?foo=bar`, you need to enter `https://example.com/?foo=bar&hjDelay=10000`.

**5)** You now have to access at least once the page with the delay that you have specified in order to get the screenshot. That would be `https://example.com/?hjDelay=10000` and not just the base URL.

**6)** Once you access the page, make sure to activate all interactive elements before the time has ran out and after that you should be able to see your new heat-map.

[image]

Comment: "That would be https://example.com/?hjDelay=10000 and not just the base URL."

That was where I was going wrong. I was acessing the base URL. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad that I can help :)